# is there any way to set the markeredgecolor globally?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to set `plt.rc('lines',ec='none')`
but it raised an error:

```
KeyError: 'Unrecognized key "lines.edgecolor" for group "lines" and name "edgecolor"'

>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.3.1'
```

It is against the document:

http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html

Answer (score 0):

I checked the best documentation (the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/master/lib/matplotlib)). The `lines.edgecolor` or `lines.markeredgecolor` (latter would be more logical) is just not there.

But as `matplotlib` is mostly written in Python, you can patch it yourself, if you want. If I did not understand something wrong, it only needs to be set in two files. (Warning: one of these "untested, should work" pieces of art.)

**1. rcsetup.py**

Add line:

```
    'lines.edgecolor': ['k', validate_color],
```

into the place (around line 500) where the `lines.` parameters are defined

**2. lines.py**

Add lines:

```
    if markeredgecolor is None:
        markeredgecolor = rcParams['lines.edgecolor']
```

among the similar statements around line 300.

Comment: so u can not do the documented rc('lines',ec=<color code>) either? Then it is a bug in doc or code. I have to report this. Thanks